# TypeError: takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python

Write a function so that the main program below can be replaced by the simpler code that calls function mph_and_minutes_to_miles(). Original main program:

```
miles_per_hour = float(input())
minutes_traveled = float(input())
hours_traveled = minutes_traveled / 60.0
miles_traveled = hours_traveled * miles_per_hour

print('Miles: %f' % miles_traveled)
```

That is the problem.

```
def mph_and_minutes_to_miles(miles_per_hour, minutes_traveled):
    minutes_traveled = float(input())
    hours_traveled = minutes_traveled / 60
    miles = (minutes_traveled / 60) * miles_per_hour

miles_per_hour = float(input())
minutes_traveled = float(input())

print('Miles: %f' % mph_and_minutes_to_miles(miles_per_hour, minutes_traveled))
```

TypeError: must be real number, not NoneType

Comment: Look at how you're invoking the mph function: `mph_and_minutes_to_miles(miles_per_hour, minutes_traveled)` -- how many parameters can it take?  how many are you passing it?

Comment: `mph_and_minutes_to_miles(miles_per_hour, minutes_traveled)` passes two arguments to a function that accepts exactly one, as the signature says: `def mph_and_minutes_to_miles(miles_per_hour)`

Comment: Yes, that line is built into the homework software, and it does not allow me to modify it.

Comment: The three lines beginning with taking input for miles_per_hour are not editable.

Comment: So fix your function. What is unclear?

Comment: I'll edit my post to what I have now, but I am now getting TypeError: must be real number, not NoneType, in relation to line 9.

Comment: Your `mph_etc` function has no `return` statement. Add `return miles` at the end of the function

Comment: Thank you, with this and a little more thought, I realized several of the blatant errors I had left sitting in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options here, just replace ONLY ONE of the following

```
def mph_and_minutes_to_miles(miles_per_hour, minutes_traveled):
```

or

```
print('Miles: %f' % mph_and_minutes_to_miles(miles_per_hour))
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding this function  instead of the one you had defined in your question, should fix your error.

```
def mph_and_minutes_to_miles(miles_per_hour, minuted_traveled):
    hours_traveled = minutes_traveled / 60
    miles = hours_traveled * miles_per_hour
    return miles
```

So the total code would look like:

```
def mph_and_minutes_to_miles(miles_per_hour, minuted_traveled):
    hours_traveled = minutes_traveled / 60
    miles = hours_traveled * miles_per_hour
    return miles

miles_per_hour = float(input())
minutes_traveled = float(input())

print('Miles: %f' % mph_and_minutes_to_miles(miles_per_hour, minutes_traveled))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def mph_and_minutes_to_miles(miles_per_hour, minuted_traveled):
    
    hours_traveled = minutes_traveled / 60
    miles = (minutes_traveled / 60) * miles_per_hour
    return miles

miles_per_hour = float(input())
minutes_traveled = float(input())

print('Miles: %f' % mph_and_minutes_to_miles(miles_per_hour, minutes_traveled))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def mph_and_minutes_to_miles(miles_per_hour, minutes_traveled):
    hours = minutes_traveled / 60.0
    miles = hours * miles_per_hour

    return miles

miles_per_hour = float(input())
minutes_traveled = float(input())

print('Miles: {:f}'.format(mph_and_minutes_to_miles(miles_per_hour, minutes_traveled)))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.